# chartSeries3d0 quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

I would like to chart a 3d series in R with chartSeries3d0. The idea is pretty much to view the n rolling month return relationship between two time series.

```
require(quantmod)
source("http://www.quantmod.com/examples/chartSeries3d/chartSeries3d.alpha.R")
initDate <- "2003-01-03"
endDate <- "2012-08-10"
symbols <- c("SPY","IEF")
getSymbols(symbols, from=initDate, to=endDate, index.class=c("POSIXt","POSIXct"))
data<-merge(SPY$SPY.Adjusted,IEF$IEF.Adjusted)
data<-ROC(data,n=120)
data[is.na(data)]<-0
chartSeries3d0(data)
```

The above code gives me a really narrow 3d chart, how can I adjust the axis so they are wider?

Comment: I assume `chartSeries3d0` comes from the link I added.  Please edit if not.

Comment: yes it is, the link provides the entire source code. I tried playing around with the parameters but none modify the axis width...

Comment: Not useful enough to post as an answer, but: If I do `data=data*100` and then `chartSeries3d0(data)` I get the start of a real chart. So I think it is hard-coded to plot percentage changes.

Comment: appreciate the help, it does make it show more!